# Countif unique occurrences of the text with criteria

Tags: excel, countif

Need help to find Unique occurrences of the specific text..

Here is my example in the screenshot..

I need 2 conditions formulas

1. Count no. of unique names(J col) which are Success. but the condition here is it should be Failed if the name has 2 different statuses. i.e., Success & Failed = Failed
2. Count no. of unique names(J col) which are Success. but the condition here is between date range.  (here also Success & Failed = Failed )

[image]

Comment: Edit in your Excel version.  There is a newer UNIQUE function.

Comment: using MS365 @JodyHighroller

Comment: @JodyHighroller

Comment: pls share us which part of the effort fails.. after trying this : https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-unique-function